# Report (.rdlc) / ReportViewer - How to break textbox' text into multiple parts when it's too long?

Tags: textbox, reportviewer, report

I have a TextBox in my Report's (.rdlc) body section. The size of the textbox' value is variable (can grow). The problem is, when the value is too long, a page break is generated before the textbox. I found the same question but no luck getting access the answer http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/MS-SQL_Reporting/Q_26821256.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default the *KeepTogether* property is set to true, causing the entire textbox to move to the next page. Set *KeepTogether* to false, and it will split it across multiple pages.

Note that you can't select this option from the *TextBox Properties...* dialog box; you have to set it from the *Properties Window* (F4).

Comment: this x1,000,000. It's entirely frustrating that the two properties windows are NOT identical.

Comment: Which SSRS version include KeepTogether property ? I'm not able to find it and I'm using SSRS 2008.

Comment: @NicolaCeliento this is using the `.rdlc` reports in `Visual Studio 2010`